# undefined local variable or method `event_params' error with Rails 4 and nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I am dealing with a nested form on my current project and found a very simple blog post that has helped me alot http://iroller.ru/blog/2013/10/14/nested-model-form-in-rails-4/. The problem is that I cannot seem to update the event (which should in turn create the nested answers). I have spent most of the day today trying to work around this and I haven't been able to make any real progress.

Error

```
undefined local variable or method `event_params' for #<EventsController:0x007f9847af6d10>
```

Thanks guys and girls sorry for the dumb question. And please let me know if you would like any more information.

Models

```
 class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :questions
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
  end

  class Question < ActiveRecord::Base 
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :event
   has_many :answers
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
  end

  class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :question
  end
```

Routes.rb

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'

  devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}, controllers:        {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}

   resources :answers
   resources :users, only: [:new, :create]

   resources :questions do
     resources :answers #-> domain.com/questions/1/answers/new
   end

   resources :events, only: [:index, :new, :show, :update] do
     patch ":id", action: :index
     collection do
     get :favorite
     get "question/:id", action: :question
   end
  end

  get 'users/new', to: 'users#new'
  post 'users/new', to: 'users#create'
  get 'events/favorite', to: 'events#favorite', via:[:get], as: 'favorite'
  post 'events/:id' => 'events#update'
  get 'answers/new' => 'answers#new'
  get 'events/question' => 'events#question'
 end
```

methods from events_controller

```
 def question
   @event = Event.find(params[:id])
 end 


 def update
   @event = Event.find(params[:id])

   if @event.update(event_params)
     redirect_to events_path, notice: "Answers saved"
   else
     redirect_to events_question_path, notice: "Answers not saved"
   end
 end



 def event_params
     params.require(:event).permit(:owner_id,
     questions_attributes: [:poll, :event_id],
     answers_attributes: [:response, :event_id, :question_id, :user_id])
 end
```

questions.erb

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@event) do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_notification %>
   <%= f.object.name %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :questions, f.object.questions do |q| %>
    <%= q.object.poll%>
  <%= q.simple_fields_for :answers, q.object.answers.build do |a|%>
    <%= a.text_field :response %>
  <% end %>
 <%end %>
 <%= f.button :submit%>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: So, `event_params` method in the same controller?

Comment: @zishe yep thats correct. I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: But it won't solve the error, i guess you have mistyped, just copy one mane to another, to be sure.

Comment: k i have implemented the updates but as you said it would its still throwing the same error. could you clarify what a mane is?

Comment: Mistyped, i meant name of the method.

Comment: still throwing the same error

Comment: unfortunately another typo on my part. the end is there in my code. apologies again.

Comment: Show me all file, on pastebin or github gist. Or maybe your project on the github?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Q02v27WH heres the event controller. apologies for the mess.

Comment: Ok, you `event_params` method located in `favorite` method, so move in in the controller, 1 level down=)

Comment: I AM AN IDIOT YOU ARE AWESOME. If you're ever in the states I'm buying you a beer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no method `event_params`, or probably it is not available for class. In your case it is in the another method:

```
def favorite
  @arr = []
  cookies.each do |cookie|
    @arr.push(cookie)
    endhtm
    @info = []

    for i in 0...@arr.length
      if @arr[i][0].index('id')
        @info.push(@arr[i][1])
      end
      @info
    end

    if @info == []
      flash[:error] = "You don't have any events saved yet. Please select events of interest to you."
      redirect_to events_path
    else
      @events = Event.all_events_by_asc_order.where(id: @info)
    end
  end

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(
        questions_attributes: [:poll, answers_attributes: [:response]])
  end
end
```

Should be:

```
def favorite
  @arr = []
  cookies.each do |cookie|
    @arr.push(cookie)
    endhtm
    @info = []

    for i in 0...@arr.length
      if @arr[i][0].index('id')
        @info.push(@arr[i][1])
      end
      @info
    end

    if @info == []
      flash[:error] = "You don't have any events saved yet. Please select events of interest to you."
      redirect_to events_path
    else
      @events = Event.all_events_by_asc_order.where(id: @info)
    end
  end
end

def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(
      questions_attributes: [:poll, answers_attributes: [:response]])
end
```

There is `endhtm`, seems like it was `end` + something.